# Java: Print a range of lines from a text file

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a text file containing data about every hurricane since 1995.
Each line is formatted in the same manner, for example, a line would look like this -   `1995   Iris   2   965   109.35`

My issue is that I want to be able to input a specified range, and then print all the lines within this range. So if I input 2001 as the starting year and 2005 as the final year, I want to print every line from the year 2001 to 2005.

I have stored the lines in an array, so if I type `System.out.println(dataArray[143]);` it prints just fine. But I want a range, not just a single specific year, and everything I try returns an error.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Edit---
Here is a bit of the code.

```
if(response.equals("1995")) {
         for (int j = 11; j >= 0; j--) {
              if (h - j >= 0) {
                  System.out.println(dataArray[h - j]);
                }
            }
    }
```

This does work (for a single year) and prints every line for 1995 but repeats the first hurricane of 1995. My attempts at trying to end the loop after the final year has printed are god awful as I am struggling to incorporate user input.

Comment: Possibly start by reading it in as `csv` data with tabs as delimiter.

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help you, we'll need the minimal relevant portion of the code you've tried, and the current error you're receiving.

Comment: just loop over the array with specific range and print your result

Comment: Why not to store data in Map having key as Year and value as List of lines for each year .   ie Map<String,List<String>> hurricaneData. You can search for keys range and get data for multiple years

Comment: In your questioned, you tagged `ArrayList` but your question doesn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it differently, since we know the first string in every line is the year in which hurricane occured, while reading the line, i would get the year in which hurrican occured.
The data structure I would be using is a Map> where key is the year and List would store all the lines for that year.
Post that given a range of years, it should be trivial to extract all hurricanes which occured in that particular year using

```
 for(String year: yearList){
   List<String> hurricanes = map.get(year);
   for (String hurricane: hurricanes){
        System.out.println(hurricane);
   }
  }
```